# move sidebar from left to right

Tags: html, css

i've made an html page (documenter) using this tool http://revaxarts-themes.com/documenter/ and when im done i've seen the result here http://documenterdocs.revaxarts.com/doc_acc064384c5cd60a82f77cf3ada4ea09/ now im wondering since i have the source code of it HTML and CSS, how i can move the sidebar from left to the right so i could convert language, pleas help

Answer (score 3):

In your `style.css` file:
content is a  div

```
#content {
  float:left;
  width:588px;
}
#sidebar {
  float:right;
  width:272px;
}
```

Just guess what values you have to change ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever u want to move any thing from left to right, can be done using the property float, `float: right` will move the thing from left to right.